# Strange offset empty space in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm now developing a website, I have a header as usual. But there is a problem in search textBox input with IE7. When I look at there with IE developer tools I see strange LEFT offset this is what the problem is actually. Any helps appreciated. 
[image]

[This is where you can see the problem](http://www.beratuslu.com/share/ie7/index.html)

[source code(.rar)](http://www.beratuslu.com/share/ie7.rar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add display:inline; to #searchBox

and addjust 1 or 2 px width of your button, problem will be solved

this problem arise in IE6 & 7, its called double float margin bug, when you apply margin to the first floating element, its margen get doubled in IE6 & 7.

Comment: the double-margin bug affects IE6 but not IE7: see http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

Comment: Fabrizio, what scope this probemlem belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

Try to enclose the  field in a div.
e.g.

```
<div><input type="text"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is the margin on `#searchBox` - `margin: 14px 0 0 97px`

Changing the margin on `#searchBox` will move the input field.

Comment: yes. It is but this time I dont know how I give margin between blue box and search box.?